# Open Source way to batch reduce export quality?

Tags: image-processing, batch

In Photoshop, we have actions, we can record macros and replay it on other images. One of the options I liked was that we can control the image quality when exporting jpgs.

I have stopped using Photoshop long back.

I have GIMP and the closest desired output I have reached it use [BIMP](https://alessandrofrancesconi.it/projects/bimp/) to *reduce the image size* (dimension) which is not exactly what I'm looking for.

How do you batch process your images to reduce image quality to say, 60%?

Comment: Do you want to reduce the size or you want to increase the compression?

Comment: @RomeoNinov Not sure if they are same or different. Can you explain a bit? Won't increasing the compression reduce the size?

Comment: @SantoshKumar, by reducing the size I mean image dimensions (because they are also image size).

Comment: @RomeoNinov No, not the dimensions. that is the limitation BIMP is giving me right now. I want to reduce the quality. Is it the compression level which controls the quality?

Comment: Yes, compression level control the quality, But the relation is not linear and also depend of the subject on the photo (because of the JPEG compression algorithm)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use free (but not opensource) software as XnView. Batch convert give you the option to define quality level:
[image]

Or you can use free and opensource ImageMagick by [convert with set compression/quality](https://legacy.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=34625):

```
magick in.jpg  -quality 65 out.jpg
```

(quality set to 65)
Also you can check [this Q/A in StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261855/recommendation-for-compressing-jpg-files-with-imagemagick)

Answer (score 6):

For a batch process, nothing is better than [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/index.php). In a terminal:

- The very simple `mogrify` that overwrites the input file

```
magick mogrify -quality 60 *.jpg
```

- The slightly more complex `convert` (because we have tell IM how to compute the output filename from the input one:

```
convert *.jpg -quality 60 -set filename:fname '%t-q60' '%[filename:fname].jpg'
```

Comment: Is ImageMagick available for Windows?

Comment: Yes, Windows, OSX, all Unix flavors... Free, open source... See link in answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Nconvert](https://www.xnview.com/en/nconvert/) is a command line program that is handy to use in batch scripts. Its counterpart, [XnView](https://www.xnview.com/en/xnview/), uses a graphical interface. These are not open source, but are free for non-commercial use.
 ImageMagick is open source, but harder to figure out.